# Button Upload to App Store doesn't exist after archive apps

Tags: xcode

I'm trying to upload iOS app to test flight and all the instruction told me to archive and then click 'Upload to App Store' button. However, it doesn't exist at mine. What I should do?

[image]

Comment: Select "Distribute App" and then you will be presented with the App Store option.

Comment: It works! Thank you! @TodorBrachkov !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tap on **Distribute** app then you'll be presented with 4 options:-
    1. iOS app store
    2. Ad hoc
    3. Enterprise
    4. Development

Tap on 1st option '**iOS App store**' & say 'Next'

[image]